# Imporing data manually with GUI MongoDB causes ReferenceError: collection is not defined?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

I'm getting this error on an existing collection  when I tried to aggregate to join two collections

`show dbs`

> Bankerise   172 kB
> admin       102 kB
> config     73.7 kB
> local      73.7 kB

`use Bankerise`

> switched to db Bankerise

`show collections`

> usedData
> UserApp

```
db.usedData.aggregate( [    { 
     $lookup : {
                 from: UserApp,
                localField:"id",
                   foreignField: "id", as:"same_id"       
                }   
     }])
```

> [ReferenceError:](https://github.com/SabriMahmoud/GDPR_Compliance_BigData_Systems/issues/new#) UserApp is not defined

And I thing it raises from the fact that I have imported the data Manually using GUI.

I'm missing something here ?

Comment: That is a syntax error for the `$lookup` usage.

Comment: @prasad_ No it is not a syntax error because I tried to create the collection with the command db.createCollection(" coll ") and inserted data with db.coll.insertMany() with the same syntax it works .

Comment: @prasad_ the problem occurs only when importing the data manually

Comment: I'm sorry you are right about it it was missing " " for UserApp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Mr [prasad_](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4679320/prasad) wrote in comments it is a syntax error it was missing **" "** on **UserApp**